# Tabs and back button. How to prevent the user exits the application

Tags: android

I'm using tab host and fragments to display several pages. Right now, when I press a tab and then a back button, the user gets out of my application. I want to prevent that, so when there is nothing in the stack of fragments a dialog appears asking if the user wants to leave or not the app. The solution that I'm giving to that is when back button is pressed I see what fragment is shown right now, if is any of the principal tabs I show the dialog. That works fine, but I only want to show the dialog only if there is nothing else to show, when back button is pressed. I will try to explain my self better with an example:

Suppose I have tabs A, B, C, D.

For each tab, I have a fragment that shows its content: Fragment_A, Fragment_B, Fragment_C, Fragment_D.

From Fragment_A, I can go to Fragment_C, Fragment_W, Fragment_Z.

Suppose now that I'm in fragment_A and then I press a button that takes me to Fragment_C. In my stack I have: fragment_A, fragment_C. As fragment_C is a principal tab, when I press back button my solution will shows the dialog. But I dont want this behavior, I want to go back to fragment_A. And then if the user press back button again, I want to display the dialog because there is nothing else in my stack.

This is what I have:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { 

    Fragment currentFragment = this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.tabcontent);

    String fragmentTag = currentFragment.getTag().toString();


    if (fragmentTag.equals(tagFragmentClients) || fragmentTag.equals(tagFragmentTasks) || fragmentTag.equals(tagFragmentSettings) || fragmentTag.equals(tagFragmentLogout)){

        showDialog();

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't advise this as it is not normal behaviour, users of your app will not expect this. Since every other app on their devices acts differently.

Comment: And if the user click A, B, C, when it uses the back button the behavior should be c -> B -> A? Also, it's not clear what the behavior should be for Fragment_W, Fragment_Z. If you want to replicate the user going through the tabs then store the user path in a structure of your choice(adding the tab number in onTabChanged) from which you'd pop tabs in reverse on a user back button action. And like Blundell already said, I don't find this behavior appropriate.

Comment: "And if the user click A, B, C, when it uses the back button the behavior should be c -> B -> A". Sorry, yes thats correct. The idea is to know when I should avoid the user to exit the application without notice. If this not a normal behavior, what should be?. In a certain point, if the user travels for all the fragments and press back button until get the first fragment, the application will end. I just want to prevent this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not normal android behavior, but I suppose you could use `FragmentManager` `getBackStackEntryCount()` method to determine the size of your backstack, and if it equals 0 you can show your alert dialog.